# Representing a Rayleigh distribution by Gamma distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

Rayleigh distribution is formulated as $$P(x\mid\sigma)=\frac{x}{\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{\sigma^2}\right) \,,\tag{1}$$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance. $Z$ is a complex variable specified as $Z=a+jb$.

A paper said that Gamma distribution $\Gamma(k,\theta)$ can represents the Rayleigh distribution when $k=\theta=1$.

I know that $\Gamma(k,\theta)=\frac{x^{k-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)}$ and $\Gamma(1,1)=e^{-x}$ which is unequal to the above Rayleigh distribution $(1)$.

I don't understand why the Gamma distribution can represent the Rayleigh distribution and if the conclusion is correct how to prove that?

Thanks a lot! :  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is wrong! (better, the statement is correct but ***something was left implied***)

1. Some notes:

- The density you call Rayleigh is not a nice density. The Rayleigh's density is the following, for $x>0$

$$f_X(x;\sigma^2)=\frac{x}{\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

- The variance is $V[X]=(2-\frac{\pi}{2})\sigma^2$

2. to Represent a Rayleigh with a Gamma you have to do a variable transform:

If X is a $Gamma(n,\theta)$ and you transform it with

$Y=\sqrt{X}$ then your statement is correct.

$f(y;1;1) \sim Ray(\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: @heng zhu :  Just FYK: In a more usual way,  a Rayleigh can be also represented by a Weibull Law

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The paper does have a assumption that  $a$ and $b$ are i.i.d with $\mathcal {N}(0,\frac{1}{2})$. In addition, if $X$ is a vector consisted with $n$ complexs like $Z$, i want to konw whether $||X||^2_2$ obey $\chi^2(n)$ and $\Gamma(n,1)$？